# PyQt4: setVerticalHeaderLabels to checkbox

Tags: python, checkbox, label, pyqt4, qtreewidget

How can you `setVerticalHeaderLabels` of a `QTableWidget` to a checkbox if possible using python?

This would be the relevant part of the code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        self.updateTable()

    def updateTable(self):
        table_rows = range(0,1)
        table_cols = range(0,1)

        self.table.setRowCount(len(table_rows))
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(table_cols))

        vertical_label = [self.tableCheckbox() for row in table_rows]
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(vertical_label)

    def tableCheckbox(self):
        chkBoxItem = QTableWidgetItem()
        chkBoxItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        chkBoxItem.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        return chkBoxItem

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code will raise `TypeError: QTableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(QStringList): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'` because `QTableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels()` is expecting a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should use `setVerticalHeaderItem` and create your custom `QTableWidgetItem` subclass that looks like a checkbox.

`QTableWidgetItem` has the `checkState` and `setCheckState` methods, so something like what you're requiring should be possible.

Alas I've never had this need so I can't provide you with more insights.

edit:
Just to clarify: `setVerticalHeaderLabel(s)` is completely wrong for what you're trying to do.
It's just a convenience method to create a `QTableWidgetItem` with the given text and add it as an header. If you want customization you must use `setVerticalHeaderItem`.